# Formatting numbers with NumberFormat and BigDecimal.movePointRight()

Tags: java, jasper-reports, number-formatting, bigdecimal

I have to format values from a database to display this values in a frontend. The database values looks like this: `0.0009` and the output have to look like this `0,09`.

`($F{Param1} == null) ? "" : NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN).format($F{Param1}.movePointRight(2)) + " %"`

To getting this format I first use `BigDecimal.movePointRight(2)` to remove zeros from the number. This works fine and with the example above. I get the value `0.09` displayed. Because I need the german number format I replace the decimal point with `NumberFormat(Locale.GERMAN)` and this converts `0.09` to `0,09`. So perfect - it works. But I also get values  like `0.0000` from database. With the code above `0.0000` is formatted to a single `0`. In fact `0.00` is needed. I understand that `NumberFormat()` produces this.

Is there a more elegant way to format a number from `0.0000` to `0,00`? I'm looking to the `DecimalFormat` class, but found no valid pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
double d = 0.0009;
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.GERMANY, "%,.2f", d));
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't mention that I also get values like 0.0009 from database. With your code 0.0009 is formatted to 0,00 too. I will edit the initial post.

Comment: Just getting the idea to use the replace function of String: `($F{Param1} == null) ? "" : $F{Param1}.movePointRight(2).toString().replace(".", ",") + "%"`  That's fixed it.